# UIDatePicker TimeZone issue

Tags: objective-c, timezone, uidatepicker

I have run across an odd issue with a `UIDatePicker`. I am trying to make an app that allows me to set reminders based on other time zones. IE. remind me when it is 4pm in New York.

When using the `UIDatePicker`, the `NSDate` object that is returned is always the selected time in the phone's time zone, converted to UTC. It doesn't seam to respect either the timezone or calendar properties being set to another time zone.

This is my code in all it's glory!

```
NSLog(@"Date: %@", [datePicker date]);
NSLog(@"DatePicker TimeZone: %@", [datePicker timeZone]);
NSLog(@"Calendar TimeZone: %@", [datePicker.calendar timeZone]);

NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"];

NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[cal setTimeZone:timeZone];
NSLog(@"New Calendar TimeZone: %@", [cal timeZone]);

NSLog(@"Updating timezones");
[datePicker setTimeZone:timeZone];
[datePicker setCalendar:cal];


NSLog(@"Date: %@", [datePicker date]);
NSLog(@"DatePicker TimeZone: %@", [datePicker timeZone]);
NSLog(@"Calendar TimeZone: %@", [datePicker.calendar timeZone]);
```

And the output...

```
2012-11-09 14:13:04.834 DatePickerTest[4524:c07] Date: 2012-11-09 03:12:59 +0000
2012-11-09 14:13:04.835 DatePickerTest[4524:c07] DatePicker TimeZone: (null)
2012-11-09 14:13:04.837 DatePickerTest[4524:c07] Calendar TimeZone: Australia/Sydney (GMT+11:00) offset 39600 (Daylight)
2012-11-09 14:13:04.837 DatePickerTest[4524:c07] New Calendar TimeZone: America/New_York (EST) offset -18000
2012-11-09 14:13:04.837 DatePickerTest[4524:c07] Updating timezones
2012-11-09 14:13:04.882 DatePickerTest[4524:c07] Date: 2012-11-09 03:12:59 +0000
2012-11-09 14:13:04.882 DatePickerTest[4524:c07] DatePicker TimeZone: America/New_York (EST) offset -18000
2012-11-09 14:13:04.883 DatePickerTest[4524:c07] Calendar TimeZone: America/New_York (EST) offset -18000
```

The `NSDate` returned is correct on the first line, it is the UTC time for 14:12 in sydney, but after changing the time zone and the calendar, the date returned is still the based on 14:12 in sydney, not 14:13 in New York.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4, you can change the Time Zone of the `UIDatePicker` by doing below:

Set the `datePickerMode` to `dateAndTime`, to see the time as per the Time Zone
`datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime`

Create the constant timeZone with the Time Zone you want

`let timeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: "America/New_York")`

Do the optional binding as the timeZone contains the optional value.

`guard let newTimeZone = timeZone else {return}`

Set the newTimeZone to the datePicker.timeZone

`datePicker.timeZone = newTimeZone`